# probability of selecting three numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image]

In the above question , in case 1 how they have written the numerator term .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're counting the number of length-3 geometric progressions in $\{1,2,4,\ldots,2^{2k}\}$ which is the same as the number of length-3 *arithmetic* progressions in $\{0,1,2,\ldots, 2k\}$.

In order to select a length-3 progression we can select its left and right endpoints, and then the middle term will be automatically determined. But there can only be a middle term if the distance between the endpoints is even, or in other words, if both endpoints is even *or* both endpoints are odd. But every choice of two different even endpoints or two different odd endpoints will give us a progression.

There are $k+1$ even numbers in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,2k\}$, so ${}^{k+1}C_2$ progressions that begin and end at even positions.

And there are $k$ odd numbers in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,2k\}$, so ${}^kC_2$ progressions that begin and end at odd positions.

In total, ${}^{k+1}C_2 + {}^kC_2 $.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Partition the set into two

$S_1 = {1,2^2,2^4,..2^{2k}}$ You have (k+1) numbers to select

$S_2= {2,2^3,2^5... 2^{2k-1}}$ You have k numbers to select

The two possibilities for three numbers are $S_1S_2S_2$ or $S_2S_1S_1$.

Now you will understand why you have the sum in the numerator